# how to find error why blender crashes? Eevee material mode

Tags: rendering, animation, materials, rigging, eevee-render-engine

I have an i7 7th Gen aorus 370M board with 1050ti 1TB SSD 32GB ddr4. When I open my scene and switch to the material. That load shader compilation and then not responding. After some time it's closed. Please help me or tell me how I can find errors. Using Eevee

Comment: Have you tried to append everything in the scene to a new fresh blend file? (File > Append... + choose the collections)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a system error, First check your System in ***Edit>Preference>System***, And see you have your GPU or CPU checked. Also to check for errors you can go to ***Window>Toggle System Console*** in Blender and see if any error is giving to you by maybe an outdated addon or anything.

You should try a new scene and see if any helps and if not just reinstall blender maybe something got corrupted somehow, Hope it helps